# postgresql-14 with huge_pages won't start

Tags: postgresql-14, huge-pages

If I try to enable "huge_pages = on" PostGresql fail to start :

FATAL:  could not map anonymous shared memory: Cannot allocate memory
HINT:  This error usually means that PostgreSQL's request for a shared memory segment exceeded available memory, swap space, or huge pages. To reduce the request size (currently 2768240640 bytes),

cat /proc/meminfo | grep -i huge
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
FileHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:    1000
HugePages_Free:     1000
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:         2048000 kB

Ubuntu 22.04

with a shared_buffers = 1GB it's ok but not 2GB
My server has 16GB of ram

Comment: It seems to me that there are allocated about 2GB of huge pages (1000 x 2048kB) but the request is for about 2.6GB (2768240640). Also, Hugetlb shows that exactly 1000 x 2048kB is already used.